# Google map URL to link to satellite map with a marker and respect zoom

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to create a URL that will render google maps with:

- satellite map
- a marker (pin)
- a specified zoom level

I feel like I'm going a little crazy!?

This one is close, it is a satellite map, and has a marker, but does not respect the zoom parameter: http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=18&mrt=yp&t=k&q=40.7028722+-73.9868281

This one is close too, it has a marker and respects the zoom level, but it's not a satellite map: https://www.google.com/maps/place/40.7028722+-73.9868281/@40.7028722,-73.9868281,11z

Comment: A down vote without any comment is not very productive...

Comment: To me this seems like a total valid question and it surprises me that this is actually still a thing in 2021.  I am unable to find a working solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

This is as close as I got:

http://maps.google.com/maps?t=k&q=loc:-34.887091,-56.054322&ll=-34.887091,-56.054322

It works fine most of the times, but in some mobile devices the pin does not appear in the centre of the screen.

Got some info from this site: https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

Answer (score 2):

You can tell it to use the satellite image by adding `t=k`

`http://maps.google.com/maps?t=k&q=loc:37.9531784+-122.3383102`

I you want the regular map, use `t=m`

I get a marker and satellite image with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the URLs, the second link you posted sounds like it is almost exactly what you want but it lacks the satellite view. When I went to that link I was able to enable satellite view from the bottom left button on the map. When I did that, the URL updates to...

https://www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B042'10.3%22N+73%C2%B059'12.6%22W/@40.7028722,-73.9868281,**56377m**/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d40.7028722!4d-73.9868281

Compare that to the original URL...
https://www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B042'10.3%22N+73%C2%B059'12.6%22W/@40.7028722,-73.9868281,**11z**/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d40.7028722!4d-73.9868281

The original URL has a parameter specifying what looks like zulu time, in this case 11z. The satellite map that you are wanting switches that parameter out with what appears to be a zoom level specified in meters.

Comment: This solution is not generic. If you change the lat/lng parameters in the link the resulting page is map view and not satellite view. You should change also other parts of the url that look to me as internal to google. IMO, not worth it when there are apis that *should* do this.

Answer (score -1):

`https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=map&basemap=satellite`
is the way to do the URL.

Full google maps URL documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started